# Regex help: Targeting text between *| and |*

Tags: ruby, regex

I'd love someone to help me with this regex. I'd like to be able to isolate the regex to detect characters in the string below between the `* |` and `| *`:

```
Hello this is "*|first_name||default_value|*"
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: Is that a single string? If so, are the `"`s double quote characters (which would be expressed as `\"`)?

Comment: You do not have `* |` or `| *` in your string.

Comment: iam, sawa is referring to the apparent space between `*` and `|`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
if subject =~ /\*\|\K.*?(?=\|\*)/
    match = $&
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/r/sV7gB5).

- `\*\|` matches `*|`
- `\K` tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the match it will report
- `.*?` lazily matches everything up to...
- a point where the lookahead `(?=\|\*)` can assert that what follows is `|*`

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: You're quite fond of the that `\K`, zx, eh?  Do you know in which version of Ruby it was added?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Did not work in 1.8 & 1.9, worked in 2.0 & 2.1 :)

Comment: @CarySwoveland `\K` is just a hack for engines that don't have negative lookbehind... Which is nearly all of them. :) As such, it's quite useful.

Comment: Any chance you know how to do this in JavaScript as well, as opposed to just Ruby? I realised after I asked the question, that this regex doesn't work currently in JavaScript.

Comment: Why, sure! JS has terrible regex  (unless you use the XRegexP library). It doesn't support `\K` or lookbehinds, so what we do is capture what we want to Group 1. `var myregex = /\*\|(.*?)(?=\|\*)/i;
var match = myregex.exec(subject);
if (match != null) {
 result = match[1];
}`

Comment: It's a real pleasure... Thanks for your enthusiastic feedback! See you next time. :)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing fancy:

```
'Hello this is "*|first_name||default_value|*"'[/\*\|(.+)?\|\*/,1]
  #=> "first_name||default_value"
```